# getting frm micro to macro entropy problem

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

For an ideal gas entropy forvolume change from micro to macro can be rewritten as:

$S=k\ln W$

$\Delta S= S_2-S_1=k\ln W_2-k\ln W_1=k \ln\frac{W_2}{W_1}  $

since we are constrained from derivation of boltzmann distribution to look at different energy states and number of ways to get the molecules distributed in a given weight W. We can say that we want to check difference in number of combinations that gives the states $W_1$ and $W_2$.

one mole has $ N_A=6.02214129(27) \times 10^{23}$

so the difference per mole basis would be:

$\Delta S= S_2-S_1=N_Ak\ln W_2-N_Ak\ln W_1=R \ln\frac{W_2}{W_1}  $

Boltzmannn introduces the two constraints for an isolated system:

$\Sigma_i \epsilon_idN_i=0 $  (a)   $\Sigma_idN_i=0$    (b)

Since entropy is based on the same i states theese must hold. In my book, Zumdahl chemical principles 6th edition, they say that:

$\frac{W_2}{W_1}=\frac{V_2}{V_1}$    (c)

$\Delta S= S_2-S_1=R\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}  $

from basic thermodynamic and a reversible process where external and internal pressure always is the same we get per mole that:

$Q_{rev}=RT\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}  $

and we see that we get macrodefintion of entropy from volume change:

$\Delta S=R\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\frac{Q_{rev}}{T}  $

For change in temperature entropy can be derived by following Atkins physical chemistry further information 15.2 in ninth edition. Since entropy is a state function we can first go along V and then T. Combining theese two justifications would get me from micro to macro for T and V and p would always follow from ideal gas law. but I don't get (c) above. Why is this ratio correct. All I get is that there is the same number of molecules in 2 and 1 which is determined from (b). Since this is based on ideal gas law we would get pV=nRT.  R is a constant. We assume T is constant from (a). n is constant from (b) then we are left with p and V to justify (c)?

Comment: This was a possiblity that was discussed. But I don't get anything of it:As W is a permutation of micro-states. Reciprocal of this is the probability of an equilikely micro-state.

p = 1/W

But, the probability of a micro-state is proportional to number of molecules (N) in a given volume. As volume is changed, the probability of finding a molecule will change.

Therefore,
 p proportional to 1/V

Hence, equating these two,

1/W proportional to 1/V

or

W proportional to V

=> W2/W1 = V2/V1
What does this mean:Reciprocal of this is the probability of an equilikely micro-state?

Comment: I think this sites is informative:http://www.pa.msu.edu/courses/2005spring/phy215/phy215wk4.pdf